# Configure logging to capture failed user login attempts

Tags: apache, tomcat, logging, configure

I am trying to configure logging to capture failed user login attempts. I think I have it all good but not seeing logs in the directory I specified (or any beyond the normal basic logging).

Where am I misconfiguring?

```
**server.xml** *Just the section in question*

Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
directory="D:/Software/logs" prefix="localhost." suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t '%r' %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/> 

**logging.properties**

handlers =      1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \ 
                2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \ 
                3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \ 
                4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, \ 
                java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, \ 
                5request-dumper.org.apache.juli.FileHandler \ 

 .handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler 


############################################################ 
# Handler specific properties. 
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers. 
############################################################ 

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE 
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = D:/Software/logs/ 
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina. 
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.limit = 100000 # size 100MB 
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.count = 5 


2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE 
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = D:/Software/logs/ 
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost. 

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE 
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = D:/Software/logs/ 
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager. 

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE 
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = D:/Software/logs/ 
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager. 

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE 
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a ConsoleHandler, so are you seeing logs on the console? If console isn't working then it's probably a problem with your log config in general. If console is working, are there any error messages? I would double check the path names since Windows can be a little tricky with escaped slash characters, but I think your path would work.